# AWS Parameter Store for Java Spring Boot 3.0

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

---

Hi,

I have the problem with configuration of the spring boot parameter store for spring-boot 3.0 application.

I have added the following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-parameter-store</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
```

And my application.properties:

```
spring.config.import=aws-parameterstore:/config/app

spring.cloud.aws.parameterstore.region=eu-west-1
```

However still i am experiencing an error:

```
Description:

Config data resource '[ParameterStoreConfigDataResource@198c7a4b context = '/config/app', optional = false]' via location 'aws-parameterstore:/config/app' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'aws-parameterstore:/config/app' is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

Do I miss any of the dependencies or additional configuration?

Comment: is this solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it working by adding the following dependency:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.0.1")
```